# How to print a file to an html page in django

Tags: html, django

I have a Django application where the logging is being printed to a file using the `logging` module.

I want to be able to have the contents of the log file also display on an html page such if a new line gets printed to the log page, the html page will also actively update to display the new line without having to be refreshed.

How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for updating HTML without refreshing the page.

Create or edit the HTML with JavaScript and use AJAX for fetching latest logs every x seconds or how often you want the page to update. AJAX calls some Django view that returns the log data. For example, the view could read 10 latest lines from a log file and return that. JSON is probably the easiest format to work with but any format is fine (doesn't have to be XML like in the picture).

[Tutorial for doing something like this with Django + jQuery](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

[image]

Depending on how complicated the logging page is, you may want to check out [Django's documentation for JavaScript](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/javascript/), [storing JavaScript files in the project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) if JS code is not just in the HTML files, [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and different JavaScript libraries/frameworks such as [React](https://reactjs.org/) or [Vue](https://vuejs.org/).